# Image segmentation using clustering? can dendrogram helps?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, hierarchical-clustering

I have constructed dendrogram for the image and I want to segment it

```
clear all;close all;
maxclust=3
RGB = imread('yellowlily.jpg');
imshow(RGB,'InitialMagnification',50)
RGB=rgb2gray(RGB);
rgb=double(RGB);
T = clusterdata(rgb,'maxclust',3);
X2=zscore(rgb);% standardized data
Y2=pdist(X2);% distance calculation
% % The connection between Step2 making making variable definition
Z2=linkage(Y2);
% % Step3 making clustering information
C2=cophenet(Z2,Y2); 
% % Step4 create cluster, and make a pedigree chart
T=cluster(Z2,6);
H=dendrogram(Z2);
```

From this dendogram I got two branches. Whether it deals with 2 objects???

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you explain what the problem is? What is the result that you want to obtain?

Comment: I want to segment an image using hiearchichal clustering.i just tried few lines.

Comment: Your description is vague. It doesn't help much. What is the question?

Comment: perform clustering on image and produces segmentation of image

Comment: Can you upload an image of the dendogram plot?